# How to Solve This Exponential Limit without Derivate / L'Hôspital's Rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

can someone teach me how can I solve this limit without using the L'Hopital's Rule?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{2+x^{2}}{2-x^{2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\left( \frac{2+x^{2}}{2-x^{2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\left(1+ \frac{1}{1-x^2/2} \cdot x^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Comment: $$\lim_{ x\to 0 } \left( \dfrac{ 2+x^{2} }{ 2-x^{2} } \right)^{ \dfrac{1}{x^2} } \Rightarrow  \lim_{ x\to \infty } \left( \dfrac{ 2+ 1/x^{2} }{ 2- 1/x^{2} } \right)^{x^2} = \lim_{ x\to \infty } \left( \dfrac{2x^2+1}{2x^2-1} \right)^{x^2} = e$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{2+x^2}{2-x^2}=1+\frac{2x^2}{2-x^2}=1+\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}
$$
and $y=\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}\to 0$, as $x\to 0$. Hence
$$
\left(1+\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^2}}=(1+y)^{1/y}\to e,
$$
as $x\to 0$.

Finally
$$
\left(\frac{2+x^2}{2-x^2}\right)^{1/x^2}=\left(\left(1+\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}}\to e,
$$
since, if $f(x)\to e$ and $g(x)\to 1$, then $f(x)^{g(x)}\to e$.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left (\frac{2+x^2}{2-x^2} \right)^{1/x^2}.$$ $$\implies L= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{\frac{(1+x^2/2)^{2/x^2}}{(1-x^2/2)^{2/x^2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{e}{e^{-1}}}=e.$$